# How do I call a jquery function to check for element visibility

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to detect visibility (partial or complete) with jQuery  of an html element with an ID of *cover* and delete the element. As it is not working I've stripped down the function to just alert a message if the element is detected. I'm using the .visible method but it's not alerting the message.

The script I've created is called checkVisible.js and is simply:

```
$(function() {
    alert('START OF FUNCTION');
    $('#cover').visible(), function() {
        alert('COVER VISIBLE');
    };
});
```

The html is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="annie.css">
    <script src="js/visible.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.visible.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/checkVisible.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="nav">
        <div id="logo"><img id="logo_img" src="images/annie2.gif"></div>
        <div id="navbar">
            <p class="hdr">SHOP</p>
            <p class="hdr">JOBS</p>
            <p class="hdr">ABOUT US</p>
            <p class="hdr">BOOKINGS</p>
            <p class="hdr">PAYMENTS</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="holder">

        <div id="lh_top_bar">
            <div id="lh_top_bar_text">ANNIE</div>
        </div>
        <div id="rh_top_bar"></div>
        <div id="lh_bar">
            <div id="line"></div>
            <div id="lh_bar_text">Collection 2016/2017</div>
        </div>

        <div class="image1">
            <img class="cs--img1" src="images/shoe_black_pair_small.jpg" alt="black shoe">
        </div>

        <div id="rh_bar">
            <div id="rh_bar_text">We will be at White Show January 20, 2017</div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom_bar">
            <div id="discover">DISCOVER COLLECTION</div>
            <div id="lh_bottom_bar"></div>
            <div id="rh_bottom_bar"></div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="holder2">

        <div id="lh_top_bar">
            <div id="lh_top_bar_text">ANNIE</div>
            </div>
            <div id="rh_top_bar"></div>
            <div id="lh_bar">
                <div id="line"></div>
                <div id="lh_bar_text">Collection 2016/2017</div>
            </div>

            <div class="image1">
                <img class="cs--img1" src="images/canstockphoto28075264.jpg" alt="gucci">

            <!--  ID="COVER"  -->

            <div id="cover"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="rh_bar">

            <div id="rh_bar_text">Instagram</div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom_bar">
            <div id="discover">INFO@DANNIECOLLECTIONS.COM</div>
            <div id="lh_bottom_bar"></div>
            <div id="rh_bottom_bar"></div>
            <div id="copyright">© 2016 ALL RIGHTS RESERVED ANNIE COLLECTIONS</div>
        </div>

    </div>


    </body>

</html>
```

It is displaying START OF FUNCTION but when the element becomes visible it does not display COVER VISIBLE.

It seems it cannot find the .visible method. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Replace it with this instead:

```
$('#cover').visible(function() { // you must wrap your function within the parentheses of visible
    alert('COVER VISIBLE');
});
```

The problem was, you were not wrapping your `function()` within the parentheses of the `visible()` function. Therefore it won't run when `visible()` is run.

Hope this help! :-)

**EDIT:**

I have noticed that `visible()` isn't actually a **jQuery** native function.

So try this in replacement:

```
if ($("#cover").is(":visible") == true) { 
    alert("COVER VISIBLE");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know visible() isn't native. It came from github and I understand it can detect when the element becomes visible in the viewport, whereas the :visible Selector deems that " Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero."   :visible does in fact work in the sense that as soon as the page is rendered, the element is detected and the alert is triggered. But this is not what I need.